# ajax real-time page refresh

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Well, in general, I'm doing a small project on django and I decided to implement a convenient search for any parameter from my form. all js was written to me by chatgpt and I don't understand it at all at all, and in general I'm working with "search" for the first time. also, what worries me now is that it is actually being searched for, but very crookedly. everything is shaking and the header is duplicated under the search. I need a dynamic page update when searching for the number, VIN, sent_at, status fields.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  Для крутых
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <input type="search" id="search-input" name="q" class="form-control form-control-dark text-bg-dark" placeholder="Поиск..." aria-label="Поиск">

        <div id="applications-list" class="mt-3">
            {% for application in applications %}
                <div class="application-item">
                    <p><strong>Имя:</strong> {{ application.name }}</p>
                    <p><strong>Номер телефона:</strong> {{ application.number }}</p>
                    <p><strong>VIN номер машины:</strong> {{ application.VIN }}</p>
                    <p><strong>Описание проблемы:</strong> {{ application.description }}</p>
                    <img src="{{ application.image.url }}">
                    <p><strong>Отправлено:</strong> {{ application.sent_at }}</p>
                    <p><strong>Статус:</strong> {{ application.status }}</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% include 'includes/pagination.html' %}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function searchAndUpdate() {
            let searchQuery = $('#search-input').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href,
                data: { q: searchQuery },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#applications-list').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        setInterval(searchAndUpdate, 5000);\
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
class ProProfile(ListView):
    paginate_by = 6
    model = Applications
    template_name = 'pages/proprofile.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            return Applications.objects.filter(
                Q(number__icontains=q) |
                Q(VIN__icontains=q) |
                Q(sent_at__icontains=q) |
                Q(status__icontains=q)
            )
        else:
            return Applications.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        applications_list = self.get_queryset()  
        paginator = Paginator(applications_list, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            applications = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            applications = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            applications = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['q'] = q
        context['applications'] = applications
        return context
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.